# Parallel Inverse Kinematics for Multithreaded Architecture (or GPU)

Tags: inverse-kinematics

[Here](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2887740), you can find a nice academic paper about this topic. What I am looking for it is a real implementation of it or, instead, any other implementation of IK algorithm that can run in a many-core or multi-core architecture? I will investigate every option you can give me. In other words, I am looking for an algorithm that can be parallelized

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Leos313, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: One might have expected the original questioner to tell us what happened when he asked the paper's authors for their implementation.

Comment: I continued to investigate and I created my own new parallelized method. [Here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9126798) it was published on IEEE Access. "Exploiting Multi-Level Parallelism for Run-Time Adaptive Inverse Kinematics on Heterogeneous MPSoCs"

Comment: should I delete the question?